# How to disable downloadable product functionality in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm using WooCommerce in a marketplace website and I am looking for a solution to disable the "downloadable product" functionality. Mainly I want that it doesn't appear in vendor's backend.

Answer (score -19, accepted):

Was having the same problem and just fixed it.

Open this file:
**...\www\Your_website_folder\wp-content\plugins\woocommerce\includes\wc_account-functions.php**

now search for the **wc_get_account_menu_items()** function (line 78)

now replace this line (line 91)

```
        'downloads'       => __( 'Downloads', 'woocommerce' ),
```

with this one

```
/*      'downloads'       => __( 'Downloads', 'woocommerce' ),*/
```

That's it.

Comment: This answer is wrong. Never modify a plugin's source, it'll just get overwritten when the plugin updates. See the below answer which explains how to properly disable the feature as intended by the plugin. http://stackoverflow.com/a/41988635/3421659

Comment: Never modify other plugins' or wordpress core code. This way you won't be able to update the plugin, for example.

Answer (score 31):

By Claudio Sanches (@claudiosanches):
Go to WooCommerce > Settings > Account and clean the downloads endpoint field.
This will disable the downloads page.

Comment: However, this does not hide the "Downloadable" option when editing a product in wp-admin...

Answer (score 25):

I got this answer here **[By Christophvh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39287308/woocommerce-remove-downloads-from-menu-in-my-account-page/39287381)** .

Go to **`WooCommerce > Settings > Advanced`** and remove the entry for **Downloads** in the **Account endpoints section**, just leave it **Blank**. And the menu will not be visible anymore. Just take a look my Attached Image.

[image]

Answer (score 17):

```
function CM_woocommerce_account_menu_items_callback($items) {
    unset( $items['downloads'] );
    return $items;
}
add_filter('woocommerce_account_menu_items', 'CM_woocommerce_account_menu_items_callback', 10, 1);
```

Used this in place of the above

Comment: +1. This is the correct answer, DON'T modify the plugin, you'll end up patching the plugin at every update, instead use the available filters as shown in this answer!

Comment: Rather than change in core file it is better to use supportive hook for any action/filter.

Answer (score 3):

This code worked for me. I got it from the Woocommerce Support.
https://wordpress.org/support/topic/remove-virtual-downloadable-products-selection/

```
function my_remove_product_type_options( $options ) {
    // uncomment this if you want to remove virtual too.
    // if ( isset( $options['virtual'] ) ) {
    //  unset( $options['virtual'] );
    // }
    if ( isset( $options['downloadable'] ) ) {
        unset( $options['downloadable'] );
    }
    return $options;
}
add_filter( 'product_type_options', 'my_remove_product_type_options' );
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I understood it correctly but if you are willing to remove "Downloads" navigation option from the "My Account" page then continue reading :)

1. Create Child Theme to your currently used theme. If you are not well known what it is read this: https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes
2. Now copy navigation.php from ...\wp-content\plugins\woocommerce\templates\myaccount\ to the Child Theme folder ...\wp-content\themes\yourtheme-child\woocommerce\myaccount\
3. Open navigation.php in your Child theme folder. Find line with function wc_get_account_menu_items() and rename the function to for example wc_get_account_menu_items_custom()
4. Open functions.php in your Child theme folder. Paste inside the file below function. Save the file and that's all. Now the "My Account" page is without "Downloads" navigation option.

   ```
   function wc_get_account_menu_items_custom() {
       $endpoints = array(
           'orders'          => get_option( 'woocommerce_myaccount_orders_endpoint', 'orders' ),
           'edit-address'    => get_option( 'woocommerce_myaccount_edit_address_endpoint', 'edit-address' ),
           'payment-methods' => get_option( 'woocommerce_myaccount_payment_methods_endpoint', 'payment-methods' ),
           'edit-account'    => get_option( 'woocommerce_myaccount_edit_account_endpoint', 'edit-account' ),
           'customer-logout' => get_option( 'woocommerce_logout_endpoint', 'customer-logout' ),
       );

       $items = array(
           'dashboard'       => __( 'Dashboard', 'woocommerce' ),
           'orders'          => __( 'Orders', 'woocommerce' ),
           'edit-address'    => __( 'Addresses', 'woocommerce' ),
           'payment-methods' => __( 'Payment Methods', 'woocommerce' ),
           'edit-account'    => __( 'Account Details', 'woocommerce' ),
           'customer-logout' => __( 'Logout', 'woocommerce' ),
       );

       // Remove missing endpoints.
       foreach ( $endpoints as $endpoint_id => $endpoint ) {
           if ( empty( $endpoint ) ) {
               unset( $items[ $endpoint_id ] );
           }
       }

       // Check if payment gateways support add new payment methods.
       if ( isset( $items['payment-methods'] ) ) {
           $support_payment_methods = false;
           foreach ( WC()->payment_gateways->get_available_payment_gateways() as $gateway ) {
               if ( $gateway->supports( 'add_payment_method' ) || $gateway->supports( 'tokenization' ) ) {
                   $support_payment_methods = true;
                   break;
               }
           }

           if ( ! $support_payment_methods ) {
               unset( $items['payment-methods'] );
           }
       }

       return apply_filters( 'woocommerce_account_menu_items_custom', $items );
   }
   ```

   Note: This is edited original WooCommerce function. There are just deleted array fields mentioning "Downloads" option.
   Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Ok so based on all of the answers above, I've put together an "all-in-one" solution which disables:

- The download endpoint.
- The checkbox options from the admin product editor.
- The dropdown options from Product Type Filter.
- The downloads metabox from orders.

---

**File:** class-disablewoocommerceproducttypes.php

```php
class DisableWooCommerceProductTypes {

    /**
     * @var array Product types in this property will be disabled.
     */
    public $disabled = [
        'virtual',
        'downloadable'
    ];

    /**
     * @var array WooCommerce uses different references for the same product types.
     */
    private $aliases = [
        'downloadable' => [ 'downloads' ]
    ];

    /**
     * @var int The priority of these overrides.
     */
    public $priority = PHP_INT_MAX;

    /**
     * @var null|string|array $product_types Accepts a string or array of 'virtual' and/or 'downloadable' product types.
     */
    public function __construct( $product_types = null ) {

        if ( $product_types ) {
            $this->disabled = (array)$product_types;
        }

        add_filter( 'product_type_options', [ $this, 'disable_admin_options' ], $this->priority );
        add_filter( 'woocommerce_account_menu_items', [ $this, 'disable_frontend_nav_items' ], $this->priority );
        add_filter( 'add_meta_boxes', [ $this, 'disable_admin_metabox' ], $this->priority );
        add_filter( 'woocommerce_products_admin_list_table_filters', [ $this, 'disable_admin_filters' ], $this->priority );

        // Disable the downloads endpoint
        if ( $this->is_disabled( 'downloadable' ) ) {
            add_filter( 'default_option_woocommerce_myaccount_downloads_endpoint', '__return_null' );
            add_filter( 'option_woocommerce_myaccount_downloads_endpoint', '__return_null' );
        }

    }

    /**
     * Quickly check if a product type is disabled. Returns primary key if $type is an alias and disabled.
     *
     * @param string $type
     * @param bool $aliases Check for aliases.
     * @return bool|string
     */
    private function is_disabled( string $type, bool $aliases = true ) {
        $basic_check = in_array( $type, $this->disabled );

        if ( $aliases && !$basic_check ) {
            foreach ( $this->aliases as $_type => $_aliases ) {
                if ( in_array( $type, $_aliases ) && $this->is_disabled( $_type, false ) ) {
                    return $_type;
                }
            }
        }

        return $basic_check;
    }

    /**
     * Remove product type checkboxes from product editor.
     *
     * @param array $types
     * @return array
     */
    public function disable_admin_options( $types ) {
        foreach ( $types as $key => $value ) {
            if ( $this->is_disabled( $key ) ) {
                unset( $types[ $key ] );
            }
        }
        return $types;
    }

    /**
     * Removes product type page from `wc_get_account_menu_items()`
     *
     * @param array $items
     * @return array
     */
    public function disable_frontend_nav_items( $items ) {
        foreach ( $items as $key => $value ) {
            if ( $this->is_disabled( $key ) ) {
                unset( $items[ $key ] );
            }
        }
        return $items;
    }

    /**
     * Removes the downloads metabox from orders.
     */
    public function disable_admin_metabox() {
        if ( $this->is_disabled( 'downloadable' ) ) {
            remove_meta_box( 'woocommerce-order-downloads', 'shop_order', 'normal' );
        }
    }

    /**
     * Add our admin product table filter modifier.
     *
     * @param array $filters
     * @return array
     */
    public function disable_admin_filters( $filters ) {
        if ( isset( $filters[ 'product_type' ] ) ) {
            $filters[ 'product_type' ] = [ $this, 'disable_product_type_filters' ];
        }
        return $filters;
    }

    /**
     * Remove disabled product types from the admin products table filters.
     */
    public function disable_product_type_filters() {
        $current_product_type = isset( $_REQUEST['product_type'] ) ? wc_clean( wp_unslash( $_REQUEST['product_type'] ) ) : false; // WPCS: input var ok, sanitization ok.
        $output               = '<select name="product_type" id="dropdown_product_type"><option value="">' . esc_html__( 'Filter by product type', 'woocommerce' ) . '</option>';

        foreach ( wc_get_product_types() as $value => $label ) {
            $output .= '<option value="' . esc_attr( $value ) . '" ';
            $output .= selected( $value, $current_product_type, false );
            $output .= '>' . esc_html( $label ) . '</option>';

            if ( 'simple' === $value ) {

                if ( !$this->is_disabled( 'downloadable' ) ) {
                    $output .= '<option value="downloadable" ';
                    $output .= selected( 'downloadable', $current_product_type, false );
                    $output .= '> ' . ( is_rtl() ? '&larr;' : '&rarr;' ) . ' ' . esc_html__( 'Downloadable', 'woocommerce' ) . '</option>';
                }

                if ( !$this->is_disabled( 'virtual' ) ) {
                    $output .= '<option value="virtual" ';
                    $output .= selected( 'virtual', $current_product_type, false );
                    $output .= '> ' . ( is_rtl() ? '&larr;' : '&rarr;' ) . ' ' . esc_html__( 'Virtual', 'woocommerce' ) . '</option>';
                }
            }
        }

        $output .= '</select>';
        echo $output; // WPCS: XSS ok.
    }

}
```

---

**File:** functions.php

```php
include_once get_theme_file_path( 'path/to/class-disablewoocommerceproducttypes.php' );

new DisableWooCommerceProductTypes();
```

---

By default the above will disable both `downloadable` and `virtual` product types.

To disable a single product type simply pass the type to the class constructor...

```php
// Example usage for just `downloadable` product type
new DisableWooCommerceProductTypes( 'downloadable' );
```

```php
// Example usage for just `virtual` product type
new DisableWooCommerceProductTypes( 'virtual' );
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of extra steps to *completely* remove the functionality.

Reviewing them all:

1. as per [Osmar Sanches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38666414/how-to-disable-downloadable-product-functionality-in-woocommerce/41988635#41988635) and [MD Ashik](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38666414/how-to-disable-downloadable-product-functionality-in-woocommerce/52376345#52376345) answers, clear the endpoint on **WooCommerce > Settings > Advanced > Downloads**
2. add the filter **`product_type_options`** as per [Maher Aldous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38666414/how-to-disable-downloadable-product-functionality-in-woocommerce/57327314#57327314)
3. remove the "Dropdown Options from Product Type Filter" as per [this blog post](https://rudrastyh.com/woocommerce/remove-virtual-and-downloadable.html) by Misha Rudrasyth:

   ```
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_products_admin_list_table_filters', function( $filters ) {
        if( isset( $filters[ 'product_type' ] ) ) {
            $filters[ 'product_type' ] = 'misha_product_type_callback';
        }
        return $filters;
    });

    function misha_product_type_callback(){
        $current_product_type = isset( $_REQUEST['product_type'] ) ? wc_clean( wp_unslash( $_REQUEST['product_type'] ) ) : false;
        $output               = '<select name="product_type" id="dropdown_product_type"><option value="">Filter by product type</option>';

        foreach ( wc_get_product_types() as $value => $label ) {
            $output .= '<option value="' . esc_attr( $value ) . '" ';
            $output .= selected( $value, $current_product_type, false );
            $output .= '>' . esc_html( $label ) . '</option>';
        }

        $output .= '</select>';
        echo $output;
    }
   ```
4. Remove the metabox "Downloadable product permissions" from Orders (edit and new):

   ```
    add_filter('add_meta_boxes', function() {
        remove_meta_box('woocommerce-order-downloads', 'shop_order', 'normal');
    }, 99 );
   ```

Answer (score -3):

CSS fix... no tampering with the functions.

```
.woocommerce-MyAccount-navigation-link--downloads {
display: none;
}
```