# WooCommerce - Remove downloads from menu in my account page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, account, hook-woocommerce

I would like to remove downloads menu from **my account page**.

How can I do this? Is it any hook to remove a specific item from the menu?

Thanks.

Answer (score 180, accepted):

Go to `WooCommerce > Settings > Advanced` and remove the entry for Downloads in the **Account endpoints** section, just leave it blank. And the menu will not be visible anymore.

[image: remove downloads link]

Comment: Hi @Christophvh, this is seems doesn't work for order. Any advise?

Comment: This is not correct or recommended method. Istead I will suggest to prefer below code written by @LoicTheAztec

Comment: @MakarandMane Why is it not "correct or recommended"? The instructions within Woocommerce state that a field can be left blank for it to be removed. Is it not preferable to keep standard behaviour instead of overriding it with code?

Comment: Account endpoints. Endpoints are appended to your page URLs to handle specific actions on the accounts pages. They should be unique and can be left blank to disable the endpoint.

Answer (score 64):

You will need this lightly customized this code snippet:

```
function custom_my_account_menu_items( $items ) {
    unset($items['downloads']);
    return $items;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_account_menu_items', 'custom_my_account_menu_items' );
```

*Code goes on functions.php file of your child theme (or in a plugin).* Tested and work.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, as it better fits WC logic

Comment: A great solution if one don't want users to add back the endpoint, but still the accepted answer gives more power to site admins.

Comment: @GabrielReguly As StackOverFlow is coding oriented, so I have answered a with coding oriented answer.

Comment: Thank you @LoicTheAztec for answering me :-) 

I agree that yours is a great solution and yes, StackOverflow is very code oriented, so your answer fits very well in the spirit of the site and I thank you for sharing it.

Still for users who don't want to mess with the code, the other solution fits them better. 

Seems that for this issue there is not an one-size-fits-all solution ;-)

Answer (score -2):

```
[data-tab="downloads"] {
    display: none!important;
}
```